# Fourier series simulator

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I've written a drawing app that turns drawings into Fourier series, but it's doing a weird thing where it spirals inwards. For some reason, all the constants of the series are similar in size (something that I believe is incorrect, but I could be wrong). Here's my code:

```js
var states = ["START", "DRAWING", "CIRCLES"];
var currentState = states[0];

var graph = [];
var constants = [];

// Half because ranging from -50 to 50
var halfNumCircles = 50;
var time = 0;
var deltaTime = 0.01;


// INITIAL SETUP
function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  angleMode(DEGREES);

  frameRate(30);
  cursor(CROSS);
}


// DRAWING LOOP
function draw() {
  background(255);

  // Axes
  stroke(100);
  line(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
  line(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);


  // Drawing
  stroke(0);
  if (currentState == states[1]) {
    // Add mousepos to graph
    graph.push([mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2]);

    // Draw graph
    for (let i = 0; i < graph.length - 1; i++) {
      line(graph[i][0] + width / 2, graph[i][1] + height / 2,
        graph[i + 1][0] + width / 2, graph[i + 1][1] + height / 2);
    }
  }


  // Circles
  stroke(0);
  if (currentState == states[2]) {
    // Starting at origin, draw lines to each boundary between circles
    var points = [[0, 0]];

    // For each constant, add a point
    for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
      // n is 0,1,-1,2,-2...
      var n = 0;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        n = -i / 2;
      } else {
        n = i / 2;
      }

      var pointX = constants[i][0] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * time) -
        constants[i][1] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * time);
      var pointY = constants[i][0] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * time) +
        constants[i][1] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * time);

      // Add new arrow to the last one
      points.push([points[points.length - 1][0] + pointX, points[points.length - 1][1] + pointY]);
    }

    // Draw lines between points
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      line(points[i][0] + width / 2, points[i][1] + height / 2,
        points[i + 1][0] + width / 2, points[i + 1][1] + height / 2)
    }

    // Increment time
    time = (time + deltaTime);
  }
}


// FOURIER SERIES OF FUNCTION
function getConstants(graph) {
  // Returns array with constants
  // Note that constants are complex numbers

  // Set constants to 0, to be added to in the next loop
  var constants = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    constants.push([0, 0]);
  }

  // For each constant
  for (let c = -halfNumCircles; c <= halfNumCircles; c++) {
    var deltaT = 1.0 / graph.length;

    // Loop through the graph: sum of f(t)*e^{-c*2pi*i*t}*deltaT from 0 <= t <= 1
    for (let i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
      // Effective points on graph
      var a = graph[i][0];
      var b = graph[i][1];

      var t = i / graph.length;

      // Complex multiplication f(t)*e^{-c*2pi*i*t}
      var xChange = a * cos(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t) - b * sin(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t);
      var yChange = a * sin(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t) + b * cos(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t);

      constants[c + halfNumCircles][0] += xChange * deltaT;
      constants[c + halfNumCircles][1] += yChange * deltaT;
    }

  }

  // Reorder from [...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2...] to [0, 1, -1, 2, -2...]
  var orderedConstants = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    orderedConstants.push([0, 0]);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      orderedConstants[i] = constants[halfNumCircles - i / 2];
    } else {
      orderedConstants[i] = constants[halfNumCircles + (i + 1) / 2];
    }
  }

  return orderedConstants;
}


// STATE CHANGING EVENTS
function mousePressed() {
  // When clicked from start, start drawing
  // When clicked from circles, reset
  if (currentState == states[0]) {
    currentState = states[1];
  } else if (currentState == states[2]) {
    currentState = states[0];
    graph = [[]];
  }
}
function mouseReleased() {
  // When released, stop drawing, start circles
  if (currentState == states[1]) {
    currentState = states[2];
    time = 0;

    // Add first element of graph to the end, creating a loop
    graph.push(graph[0]);

    // Computationally intensive step
    constants = getConstants(graph);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Circle Drawing</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.2.3/math.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="circles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style media="screen">
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't seem to find the bug. I figured it could have something to do with the scale of the input, but that wouldn't' make sense since the units are arbitrary in this case. Please let me know if you have any idea what I've done wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: > Do you have more info about it (theory behind turning the draw into Fourier series). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The unit of [`deltaTime`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/deltaTime) is milliseconds. The sample period is far too large.

Divide the time by 1000.0 to get the time in seconds:

```js
var times_s = time/1000.0;
var pointX = constants[i][0] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s) -
    constants[i][1] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s);
var pointY = constants[i][0] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s) +
    constants[i][1] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s);
```

```js
var states = ["START", "DRAWING", "CIRCLES"];
var currentState = states[0];

var graph = [];
var constants = [];

// Half because ranging from -50 to 50
var halfNumCircles = 50;
var time = 0;
var deltaTime = 0.01;


// INITIAL SETUP
function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  angleMode(DEGREES);

  frameRate(30);
  cursor(CROSS);
}


// DRAWING LOOP
function draw() {
  background(255);

  // Axes
  stroke(100);
  line(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
  line(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);


  // Drawing
  stroke(0);
  if (currentState == states[1]) {
    // Add mousepos to graph
    graph.push([mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2]);

    // Draw graph
    for (let i = 0; i < graph.length - 1; i++) {
      line(graph[i][0] + width / 2, graph[i][1] + height / 2,
        graph[i + 1][0] + width / 2, graph[i + 1][1] + height / 2);
    }
  }


  // Circles
  stroke(0);
  if (currentState == states[2]) {
    // Starting at origin, draw lines to each boundary between circles
    var points = [[0, 0]];

    // For each constant, add a point
    for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
      // n is 0,1,-1,2,-2...
      var n = 0;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        n = -i / 2;
      } else {
        n = i / 2;
      }

      var times_s = time/1000.0;
      var pointX = constants[i][0] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s) -
        constants[i][1] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s);
      var pointY = constants[i][0] * sin(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s) +
        constants[i][1] * cos(n * 2 * Math.PI * times_s);

      // Add new arrow to the last one
      points.push([points[points.length - 1][0] + pointX, points[points.length - 1][1] + pointY]);
    }

    // Draw lines between points
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      line(points[i][0] + width / 2, points[i][1] + height / 2,
        points[i + 1][0] + width / 2, points[i + 1][1] + height / 2)
    }

    // Increment time
    time = (time + deltaTime);
  }
}


// FOURIER SERIES OF FUNCTION
function getConstants(graph) {
  // Returns array with constants
  // Note that constants are complex numbers

  // Set constants to 0, to be added to in the next loop
  var constants = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    constants.push([0, 0]);
  }

  // For each constant
  for (let c = -halfNumCircles; c <= halfNumCircles; c++) {
    var deltaT = 1.0 / graph.length;

    // Loop through the graph: sum of f(t)*e^{-c*2pi*i*t}*deltaT from 0 <= t <= 1
    for (let i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
      // Effective points on graph
      var a = graph[i][0];
      var b = graph[i][1];

      var t = i / graph.length;

      // Complex multiplication f(t)*e^{-c*2pi*i*t}
      var xChange = a * cos(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t) - b * sin(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t);
      var yChange = a * sin(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t) + b * cos(-c * 2 * Math.PI * t);

      constants[c + halfNumCircles][0] += xChange * deltaT;
      constants[c + halfNumCircles][1] += yChange * deltaT;
    }

  }

  // Reorder from [...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2...] to [0, 1, -1, 2, -2...]
  var orderedConstants = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    orderedConstants.push([0, 0]);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * halfNumCircles + 1; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      orderedConstants[i] = constants[halfNumCircles - i / 2];
    } else {
      orderedConstants[i] = constants[halfNumCircles + (i + 1) / 2];
    }
  }

  return orderedConstants;
}


// STATE CHANGING EVENTS
function mousePressed() {
  // When clicked from start, start drawing
  // When clicked from circles, reset
  if (currentState == states[0]) {
    currentState = states[1];
  } else if (currentState == states[2]) {
    currentState = states[0];
    graph = [[]];
  }
}
function mouseReleased() {
  // When released, stop drawing, start circles
  if (currentState == states[1]) {
    currentState = states[2];
    time = 0;

    // Add first element of graph to the end, creating a loop
    graph.push(graph[0]);

    // Computationally intensive step
    constants = getConstants(graph);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```